# RSpec should_receive(:send).with(...): colored diff

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I'm making heavy use of RSpecs 2.13 `should_receive(:send).with(...)` feature. I know it's an outdated version, but I have to use it for one project (and the testsuite is huge).

When a spec fails, I get a diff output like this:

```
<FooBar (class)> received :send with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({ :foo => bar, :test => "hello"})
         got: ({ :foo => bar, :test => "Hello"})
```

The arguments above are all just samples. My problem is, if the hash I'm passing to `:send` is really long, it's very hard to figure out what was wrong. I enabled the colored output for RSpec, but this just colors the failing tests in red.

> Is there a way to get a colored diff output for `should_receive`?

A while ago, I wrote my own matcher `be_matching` which has colored diff output:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_matching do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual == expected
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |actual|
    difference = DiffMatcher::Difference.new(expected, actual, :color_enabled=>RSpec::configuration.color_enabled?)
    difference.to_s
  end
end
```

But it would be a lot of work, to rewrite all the tests that are using the `should_receive` syntax to use a custom matcher.

Is there a way, either built in, a gem, or a way to re-define `should_receive` to have some colored diff output for failing tests?

**EDIT:**

I found a workaround, which leads to better diff outputs. You can call the `should_receive` with a block like this:

```
  FooBar.should_receive(:send) do |arg1|
    arg1.should == {}
  end.and_return(true)
```

But still, a colored diff output without the blocks would be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Rspec will by defualt give you better diff output for arrays. I dont remember exact syntax, but for example, something like

```
expected: [a, b, c]
got:      [a, d]
diff: - [b]
        [c]
      + [d]
```

Depending on your specific case, you could convert the hash into an array to make use of that.

```
myHash.map{ |key, value| value}
```

or

```
myHash.values
```